# Django + PostgeSQL не создается таблица после миграции

Tags: django, postgresql

После создания модели в файле models.py:

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 99, unique = True)
```

и добавления приложения в файл settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #...
    'myapp',
    #...
]
```

после применения миграции в базе не создается соответствующая таблица.
Выполняю manage.py makemigrations затем manage.py migrate.
Почему не создается таблица?
Django 1.11,  PostgeSQL 10.3

Comment: Что значит "не создается"? Вы получаете ошибку? Или команды выполняются успешно, пишут, что миграции применены, но таблица в базе не появляется?

Comment: когда manage.py migrate применяю первый раз - пишет, что миграции выполнены успешно. Если отредактирую файл models.py  и пытаюсь применить миграции - пишет, что нет изменений. А таблица не создается вообще ни в каком случае

Comment: После редактирования makemigrations тоже надо выполнять.

Comment: я выполняю - пишет, что изменений не было